# Impossible to Start SQL Server browser

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I installed SQLserver Express 2012 on a Win7 machine.

The lan is made out of 2 PCs (Win7 and Win XP).

I cannot access the SQL server from the Win XP machine.

I cannot start SQL server browser.

I open the configuration tool, go to services and right click /properties on Browser. If I try to set any account (either predefined like "network service" or a real account, using the .\login syntax) I get

> WMI Provider Error (translated by me from italian)
>   Impossible to start the service. The service is not enabled or it is not linekd to any active device.
>   [0x80070422]

Can anyone tell me what to check for?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after SQL 2012 Express was installed on a windows 2012 server.

I was able to get it working by going to Administrative Tools -> Services. Found the SQL Server Browser server and started it up from there.